# SQL - Group By unique column combination

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a script that will return the latest values for a unique documentid-physician-patient triplet. I need the script to act similar to a group by statement, except group by only works with one column at a time. I need to date and status information for only the most recent unique triplet. Please let me know what you will need to see from me to help. Here is the current, very bare, statement:

```
    SELECT
        TransmissionSend.CreateTimestamp,
        TransmissionSendItem.Status,
        TransmissionSendItem.PhysicianId,
        TransmissionSendItem.DocumentIdDisplay,
        Utility.SqlFunctions_NdnListToAccountList(TransmissionSendItem.NdocNum) AS AccountNum
    FROM
        Interface_SFAX.TransmissionSend,
        Interface_SFAX.TransmissionSendItem
    WHERE
        TransmissionSend.ID = TransmissionSendItem.childsub --I don't know exactly what this does, I did not write this script. It must stay here though for the exact results.

    ORDER BY TransmissionSend.CreateTimestamp DESC -- In the end, each latest result of the unique triplet will be ordered from most recent to oldest in return
```

My question is, again, how can I limit results to only the latest status for each physician id, document id, and account number combination?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause), it's considered an SQL anti-pattern.  You may be okay with just a regular join (like you have here), but things get interesting when attempting other types.  The `WHERE` clause is what's keeping the query from returning transmissions connected to _all_ 'sent items', not just the ones that were part of _that_ transmission.  This is a key part of SQL, so I recommend picking up a few books that can go into more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First select the MAX(date) with the documentid GROUP BY documentid then select all data from the table by the first select result for example with an inner join.

```
SELECT table.additionalData, J.id, J.date
FROM table
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date) AS date 
            FROM table GROUP BY id) AS J 
ON J.id = table.id 
AND J.date /* this is the max date */ = table.date
```

Comment: Except `date` (and `table`) is a reserved word in (as near as I'm aware) all RDBMSs, and thus should be avoided (if it's even allowed).  More descriptive column names should be used in any case.

Comment: True but this just an example with the most clearest names. :-) (The reserved keywords can be escaped.)